# EExist: File already exists when using mysql on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
net.js:330
    err = this._handle.open(fd);
                       ^

Error: EEXIST: file already exists, uv_pipe_open
    at new Socket (net.js:330:24)
    at process.getStdin [as stdin] (internal/bootstrap/switches/is_main_thread.js:179:17)
    at get (<anonymous>)
    at getOwn (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:156:5)
    at NativeModule.syncExports (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:268:31)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:248:22)
    at NativeModule.getESMFacade (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:253:17)
    at NativeModule.compileForPublicLoader (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:233:10)
    at loadNativeModule (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:48:9)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:772:15) {
  errno: -17,
  code: 'EEXIST',
  syscall: 'uv_pipe_open'
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.